# dask DataFrame equivalent of pandas DataFrame sort_values

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, dask

What would be the equivalent of sort_values in pandas for a dask DataFrame ? I am trying to scale some Pandas code which has memory issues to use a dask DataFrame instead.

Would the equivalent be :

```
ddf.set_index([col1, col2], sorted=True)
```

?

Answer (score 12):

Sorting in parallel is hard.  You have two options in Dask.dataframe

#### set_index

As now, you can call set_index with a *single* column index:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: import dask.dataframe as dd

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [3, 2, 1], 'y': ['a', 'b', 'c']})

In [4]: ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

In [5]: ddf.set_index('x').compute()
Out[5]: 
   y
x   
1  c
2  b
3  a

Unfortunately dask.dataframe does not (as of November 2016) support multi-column indexes

In [6]: ddf.set_index(['x', 'y']).compute()
NotImplementedError: Dask dataframe does not yet support multi-indexes.
You tried to index with this index: ['x', 'y']
Indexes must be single columns only.
```

#### nlargest

Given how you phrased your question I suspect that this doesn't apply to you, but often cases that use sorting can get by with the much cheaper solution [nlargest](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.nlargest).

```
In [7]: ddf.x.nlargest(2).compute()
Out[7]: 
0    3
1    2
Name: x, dtype: int64

In [8]: ddf.nlargest(2, 'x').compute()
Out[8]: 
   x  y
0  3  a
1  2  b
```

Comment: Thanks Matthew. If I knew the number of rows of the dataframe in advance, then `nlargest` would work right ?

Comment: nlargest returns a dask.dataframe of a single partition, so it's generally not a good way to sort things.

Comment: So, for applying sorting operation on all the partitions and getting an ultimate result. Which way will be a good one?

Answer (score 5):

My preferred method is to first `set_index` using a single column in dask and then distribute Pandas' `sort_values` using `map_partitions`

```py
# Prepare data
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
data = dask.datasets.timeseries()

# Sort by 'name' and 'id'
data = data.set_index('name')
data = data.map_partitions(lambda df: df.sort_values(['name', 'id']))
```

One possible gotcha would that a single index value must not be in multiple partitions. From what I saw in practice though, Dask does not seem to allow that to happen. Would be good to have a more well-founded opinion on that, though.

edit: I have asked about this in [Dask dataframe: Can a single index be in multiple partitions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69570717/dask-dataframe-can-a-single-index-be-in-multiple-partitions)

Answer (score 1):

You would use this code to add a new composite column and set index to it:

```
newcol = ddf.col1 + "|" + ddf.col2
ddf = ddf.assign(ind=newcol)
ddf = ddf.set_index('ind', sorted=True)
```

If the dataframe is already sorted by (col1, col2) then it is already sorted by newcol too, so you can use sorted=True.

Comment: I don't believe this works — `sorted=True` means that you're promising Dask the index is _already_ sorted, not that you're requesting Dask sort it. See https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2388

Comment: I have fixed the explanation, it was not clear. Thank you.