# Sorting in Dask

Tags: sorting, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I want to find an alternative of **pandas.dataframe.sort_value** function in dask.
I came through **set_index**, but it would sort on a single column.

How can I sort multiple columns of Dask data frame?

Comment: Related question with additional answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40376425/dask-dataframe-equivalent-of-pandas-dataframe-sort-values

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So far Dask does not seem to support sorting by multiple columns. However, making a new column that concatenates the values of the sorted columns may be a usable work-around.

```
d['new_column'] = d.apply(lambda r: str([r.col1,r.col2]), axis=1)
d = d.set_index('new_column')
d = d.map_partitions(lambda x: x.sort_index())
```

Edit: 
The above works if you want to sort by two strings. I recommend creating integer (or bytes) columns and then using `struct.pack` to create a new composite bytes column. For example, if `col1_dt` is a datetime and `col2` is an integer:

```
import struct

# create a timedelta with seconds resolution. 
# i know this is the resolution is correct
d['col1_int'] = ((d['col1_dt'] -
                  d['col1_dt'].min())/np.timedelta64(1,'s')
                ).astype(int)

d['new_column'] = d.apply(lambda r: struct.pack("ll",r.col1_int,r.col2))
d = d.set_index('new_column')
d = d.map_partitions(lambda x: x.sort_index())
```

Comment: why do you recommend creating integer or bytes column? Does that make the sorting faster?