# build a combined coloumn in dask dataframe for sorting

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, apply, dask

[Sorting in Dask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50809462/sorting-in-dask)

based on this answer I want to build the combined column dynamically

```
df_post['sort_column'] = df_post.apply(lambda r:str([r[col1],r[col2],r[col3]]), axis=1)
df_post = df_post.set_index('sort_column')
df_post = df_post.map_partitions(lambda x: x.sort_index())
```

I am not able to figure out a way to make this '[r[col1],r[col2],r[col3]]' dynamic based on a list of columns provided by config file.

Comment: Could you post an example of your data with desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is tricky to tell what the question is after, but assuming it is "I would like to apply the solution in a the linked answer, but for a list of column names". This can look like

```
df_post['sort_column'] = df_post.apply(lambda r:str([r[c] for c in columns]), axis=1)
df_post = df_post.set_index('sort_column')
df_post = df_post.map_partitions(lambda x: x.sort_index())
```

where `columns` has been obtained from the config file beforehand.