# dask create combined column to simulate sort by 2 columns

Tags: python, dask, dask-dataframe

At the moment **df.sort_values in dask** only accept sorting by 1 column.

I have a large file that have this structure

[input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPUTU.png)

I don't know how to sort the data by first the integer column and then the date like

- 2000-01-01 ; 43000
- 2000-01-02 ; 43000
- 2000-01-01 ; 25000
- 2000-01-02 ; 25000

I think that creating a combined column and sort it will be the best option. The problem is that I don't know how to create a column that accomplish this.Maybe there is another option to do this without creating a combined column in Dask...

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50809462/sorting-in-dask

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `d['col1']` is `datetime`-type, and `d['col2']` is `int`-type:

```py
import struct
import numpy as np

# create a timedelta with days resolution as int
d['col1_int'] = ((d['col1_dt'] -
                  d['col1_dt'].min())/np.timedelta64(1,'D')
                ).astype(int)

d['sort_col'] = d.apply(lambda r: struct.pack("ll",r.col1_int,r.col2))
d = d.set_index('sort_col')
d = d.map_partitions(lambda x: x.sort_index())
```

*Reworked from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50809462/sorting-in-dask) answer*

Comment: Dask doesn't allow to add multiple columns for the sort_values....