# Dask dataframe: Can `set_index` put a single index into multiple partitions?

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, dask

Empirically it seems that whenever you `set_index` on a Dask dataframe, Dask will always put rows with equal indexes into a single partition, even if it results in wildly imbalanced partitions.

Here is a demonstration:

```py
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

users = [1]*1000 + [2]*1000 + [3]*1000

df = pd.DataFrame({'user': users})
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=1000)

ddf = ddf.set_index('user')

counts = ddf.map_partitions(lambda x: len(x)).compute()
counts.loc[counts > 0]
# 500    1000
# 999    2000
# dtype: int64
```

However, I found no guarantee of this behaviour anywhere.

I have tried to sift through the code myself but gave up. I believe one of these inter-related functions probably holds the answer:

- [`set_index`](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/8aea537d925b794a94f828d35211a5da05ad9dce/dask/dataframe/shuffle.py#L118)
- [`set_partitions`](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/8aea537d925b794a94f828d35211a5da05ad9dce/dask/dataframe/shuffle.py#L210)
- [`rearrange_by_column`](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/8aea537d925b794a94f828d35211a5da05ad9dce/dask/dataframe/shuffle.py#L398)
- [`rearrange_by_column_tasks`](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/8aea537d925b794a94f828d35211a5da05ad9dce/dask/dataframe/shuffle.py#L534)
- [`SimpleShuffleLayer`](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/cf82bb07d7070f0950b1cd7b33ff77fd384406f8/dask/layers.py#L364)

When you `set_index`, is it the case that a single index can never be in two different partitions? If not, then under what conditions does this property hold?

---

Bounty: I will award the bounty to an answer that draws from a reputable source. For example, referring to the implementation to show that this property has to hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it the case that a single index can never be in two different partitions?

No, it's certainly allowed. Dask will even intend for this to happen. However, because of a [bug](https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/8437) in `set_index`, all the data will still end up in one partition.

An extreme example (every row is the same value except one):

```py
In [1]: import dask.dataframe as dd
In [2]: import pandas as pd
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [0] + [1] * 20})
In [4]: ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=10)
In [5]: s = ddf.set_index("A")
In [6]: s.divisions
Out[6]: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
```

As you can see, Dask intends for the `0`s to be split up between multiple partitions. Yet when the shuffle actually happens, all the `0`s still end up in one partition:

```py
In [7]: import dask
In [8]: dask.compute(s.to_delayed())  # easy way to see the partitions separately
Out[8]: 
([Empty DataFrame
  Columns: []
  Index: [],
  Empty DataFrame
  Columns: []
  Index: [],
  Empty DataFrame
  Columns: []
  Index: [],
  Empty DataFrame
  Columns: []
  Index: [],
  Empty DataFrame
  Columns: []
  Index: [],
  Empty DataFrame
  Columns: []
  Index: [],
  Empty DataFrame
  Columns: []
  Index: [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],)
```

This is because the [code](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/a5aecac8313fea30c5503f534c71f325b1775b9c/dask/dataframe/shuffle.py#L796) deciding which output partition a row belongs doesn't consider duplicates in `divisions`. Treating `divisions` as a Series, it uses [`searchsorted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html) with `side="right"`, hence why all the data always ends up in the last partition.

I'll update this answer when the issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it the case that a single index can never be in two different partitions?

IIUC, the answer for practical purposes is yes.

A dask dataframe will in general have multiple partitions and dask may or may not know about the index values associated with each partition [(see `Partitions`)](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-design.html). If dask does know which partition contains which index range, then this will be reflected in `df.divisions` output (if not, the result of this call will be `None`).

When running `.set_index`, dask will compute divisions and it seems that in determining the divisions it will require that divisions are sequential and unique (except for the last element). The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/361a2f5472932cb26667216f0200b565ac67487e/dask/dataframe/shuffle.py#L190-L203).

So two potential follow-up questions: why not allow any non-sequential indexing, and as a specific case of the previous, why not allow duplicate indexes in partitions.

With regards to the first question: for smallish data it might be feasible to think about a design that allows non-sorted indexing, but you can imagine that a general non-sorted indexing won't scale well, since dask will need to store indexes for each partition somehow.

With regards to the second question: it seems that this should be possible, but it also seems that right now it's not implemented correctly. See the snippet below:

```py
# use this to generate 10 indexed partitions
import pandas as pd

for user in range(10):
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({'user_col': [user//3]*100})
    df['user'] = df['user_col']
    df = df.set_index('user')
    df.index.name = 'user_index'
    
    df.to_parquet(f'test_{user}.parquet', index=True)


# now load them into a dask dataframe
import dask.dataframe as dd

ddf = dd.read_parquet('test_*.parquet')

# dask will know about the divisions
print(ddf.known_divisions) # True

# further evidence
print(ddf.divisions) # (0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3)

# this should show three partitions, but will show only one
print(ddf.loc[0].npartitions) # 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think my question could've been clearer about the fact that I'm specifically interested in the behaviour of Dask's `set_index`. This answer is quite relevant and interesting, but doesn't address that.

Comment: Btw, for me, in your example, the divisions are actually unknown (`known_divisions` is `False)`. I'm using Dask `2021.08.01`, Pandas `1.3.1` and PyArrow `5.0.0`

Comment: No worries, I'm not confident in dask internals.

Answer (score 0):

I have just noticed that Dask's documentation for [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46842155/shuffling-data-in-dask.) says

> After this operation, rows with the same value of on will be in the same partition.

This seems to confirm my empirical observation.